# How to create multiple views in single nib file (swift 3)?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create multiple custom cells in a single Nib file, Is it possible? I'm using swift 3. please guide me through proper solution?

Comment: I do not think it is possible. What is the problem with one cell / Nib file and having multiple Nib files?

Comment: There's no problem with that but i found a method in objective c, so i think the same in swift 3 to reduce nib file.

Comment: It is possible. Please share what you need to achieve by doing so.

Comment: You can do it, but it's inefficient. Every time you load the nib file you would load all views in an array, just to get your one cell for your index path. Have each unique cell in it's own nib.

Comment: Oh, i thought it was efficient because of number of nib files are less. Thank you.